# how to extract the html and css of installed app from mobile

Tags: user-interface, mobile, mobile-angular-ui

We can get the source HTML, JS and CSS for a website by right-click and getting the source code. Is there any way we can get the same for installed Mobile app?

It is for my app. I developed a UI and installed it in my mobile to test it. Later I made some changes to my UI and couldn't recover my old changes. So I'm trying to recover it from my mobile. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah its possible but it is not a good idea. You simple dont need to do that, it is not necessary to read others work. You could get some **ideas** from that app and make / design it by your own.

Comment: It is for my app. I developed a UI and installed it in my mobile to test it. Later I made some changes to my UI and couldn't recover my old changes. So I'm trying to recover it from my mobile. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it android or IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change file extension from `ipa` or `apk` to `zip`.
Then extract it somewhere. By skimming through those files you could find those html, js and css files.

Comment: I see the app icon I installed, but not the apk file. Any specific location where the apk file gets saved?

Comment: @Sandy Well you could extract the apk file using an app called [7Zipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.joa.zipperplus7&hl=en). By going to that app and select `Applications` then check that app and select `Backup` from bottom. Or if that does not worked, [see this](http://www.wikihow.com/Extract-APK-File-of-Any-App-on-Your-Android-Phone)